Temperature controlled fan using Arduino board and LM35 temperature sensor with a ZMPT101B relay module
Parts available for the project:
Arduino board, breadboard, temperature sensor LM35, jumper wires, ZMPT101B single channel relay module 5volts, computer cooling fan, 9 volts battery snaps and battery.
So how will the connection process be for me to achieve the aim of the project since the ZMPT101B is not having an IN Pin to be connected to the Arduino board that is by so been the Arduino board can't control the ZMPT101B relay. What's the way out of this. Thanks.

From what I can see ZMPT101B is either an AC (only) voltage sensing hobbyist module or the transformer used in the module. There are plenty of tutorials for connecting the former to an Arduino. If you only have the transformer you would need to make something like the dual op-amp circuit the modules have.

I have doubts about the safety of these modules if they are to be connected to the mains.
Also I don't know why you would need one in the first place to control a fan from a temperature sensor. You would need a relay (with relay driver), a temperature sensor and the controller (presumably your Arduino). Perhaps you are confusing the blue transformer with a similar shape and colour relay?
